# kableExtra: Specify the look of selected rows programatically

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

Currently `kableExtra` 0.5.1 only supports *Specify the look of the selected row*. I wonder if there is any tweak to specify the look of selected rows programatically like `row_spec(x, c(1, 3, 4), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)`. Thanks

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

x <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "latex")
kableExtra::row_spec(x, 1, bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a loop.

```
multirow_spec <- function(x, rows, ...) {
  for (row in rows) 
    x <- kableExtra::row_spec(x, row, ...)
  x
}

x <- knitr::kable(head(mtcars), "latex")
multirow_spec(x, c(1, 3, 4), bold = TRUE, italic = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @user2554330 for nice solution. You saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Would appreciate if you help me to do similar looping with `group_rows`. Thanks